# Multi word synonym with Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using `synonym graph filter factory`

I have something as below.

```
<fieldType name="keyword" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer> 
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
   <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" expand="false"/>
   <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

synonym file contains:

btc,bfc filer,btc-filer => filer

I am searching `bfc filer`. It is not stored as `filer`. I confirmed with analysis page as below.

[image: AnalysisPage]

Comment: You're writing both `btc filer` and `bfc filer` - your screenshot shows one thing, but your text says another, and your synonym file seems to use both. Make sure you're actually testing the correct thing first - You might want have the lowercase filter first as well, and the graph filter should usually be applied when querying (since you can't index a graph).

Comment: I am correcting the statement. It was auto correction. I expect that bfc filer to be indexed as filter. It is not happening.

Comment: could you share the screenshot/details of query results for 'bfc filer' with debug=true